# Capitalize after a point in css

Tags: css

Having enough people writing in upper case, I inserted the syntax `text-transform: lowercase;` or the text to be written in lower case and syntax `::first-letter` for a capital is created after the beginning of each sentence after the point.

`text-transform: lowercase;` works fine but for `::first-letter` he created me a capital letter at the beginning of the sentence but not after!

Is it possible to create CSS capitalized after a point?

Comment: With CSS, **No** since it cannot select text nodes. You can split the text with JavaScript after a point, wrap them inside a span and then use CSS.

Comment: This is not possible with straight CSS.

Comment: @ManojKumar - you're correct, but the pseudo-element `::first-letter` only works with block level elements, so the span would need to be `display:block`.

Comment: ::first-letter capitalizes the first letter of a selector tag block, as a workaround you can try to place a <p> selector in the markup before each letter to capitalize

Comment: ok and you have examples for developing with JavaScript ?

Answer (score 0):

Keep all data into a variable and split it with the point you want. Then display all array inside paragraph. This might be working.

```
var str = "What ever you want to do. Please do it here.";
var res = str.split(".");
```

then use for loop and getElementbyId to replace the content

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
str = 'ABC. DEF. XYZ';
str2 = str.toLowerCase();
str3 = str2.replace(/\. /g, '.</span> <span class = caps>')
$('#output').html('<span class = caps>' + str3)
```

```css
.caps {
  display: inline-block;
}
.caps::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Convert the entire string to lower case; then replace the `.` with span elements; apply CSS rules to the span elements so that they are block level, inline and first letter capitalised); and just to tidy up, add an opening `<span>` before the replacement string to match the closing tag at the end of the first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    p::first-letter {
       font-weight: bold;
       color: red;
    }
</style>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById('data').innerHTML; 
    var res = str.split(".");
    var data = "";
    for(i=0; i<(res.length-1); i++){
        var data = data + "<p>"+res[i]+".</p>";
    }
document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = data;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">
<div id="data">What ever you want to do. Please do it here.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This will automatically change the data onload.

Have more questions leave me a message in [grandamour](https://grandamour.io)